# Changing configuration for other bundles using ConfigurationPlugin

Tags: configuration, osgi, karaf

I have some bundles started in karaf and want to change their configuration during start. I created class that implements ConfigurationPlugin and registered it in karaf. When I installed bundle, my configuration plugin was invoked and changed configuration, but blueprint set old config value to the bundle.

How can I use this ConfigurationPlugin for this goal?

Blueprint is very simple:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0">

    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="my" update-strategy="reload">
    </cm:property-placeholder>
    <bean id="serviceBean" class="com.mycompany.blueprint.MyServiceImpl">
        <property name="prop" value="${mydb.password}" />
    </bean>
</blueprint>
```

Configuration file contains only one encrypted property.
It should be somehow decrypted using another bundle during creation.

Comment: a bit more meat is needed here ...
how does your blueprint configuration look like?
any more participants in that game, for example do you also have configuration files?

Comment: As I found here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-4599
ConfigurationPlugin will be invoked not in all cases and seems can't be used for this purpose.